# Apple Mail - Message won't un-flag

Tags: mail.app

I have been running Apple Mail for years (too many to count) and I have never had a situation where messages won't un-flag. But currently I have about 12 messages that are stuck in "Flagged" state. They reside in various folders in Mail, but they always show up in the Flagged folder. I have tried flagging them with different flag color and unflagging them but after about a second or two they the number in the flagged folder bounces back up. When I select them and "clear flag" no flag appears on them but they stay in the flagged folder.

Any clues on how to permanently remove the flag from these message?

Comment: What mail provider do you use? It could also be a problem with them. I assume you've tried "turning it on and off again"?

Comment: This involves multiple account, my own domain as well as a gmail account. The one thing they have in common is that they come through Google, but have since been moved to a mailbox in Apple Mail.

Comment: Odd solution to be sure but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I marked your question as a duplicate so the two questions would be linked.